# GNU assembler .altmacro - suppress expansion of single-letter names in tokens like 1b?

Tags: assembly, macros, arm, gnu-assembler

I'm writing some assembly code in GNU assembler targeting ARM microcontrollers, using macros, the [`.altmacro`](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/Altmacro.html) mode, and [numeric local labels](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs-2.23.1/as/Symbol-Names.html).

The macro in question has a parameter called `b` -- and it directly maps to a parameter name called `b` in the specification of the algorithm I'm implementing, so any choice other than `b` would be actually more confusing.

Without `.altmacro`, the use of `b` is not a problem since in the regular macro mode, parameters need to be preceeded by `\` -- i.e. I would use `\b`. But apparently in `.altmacro` mode you can refer to them by their name directly, i.e. just `b`.

The following example illustrates the problem (where `b` in this case additionally doubles as the CPU's branch instruction):

```
.macro my_macro b
    // Do something with \b
1:
    b   1b
.endm

    my_macro xyz
```

Compiling this as is produces the following error:

```
Error: bad instruction `xyz 1xyz'
```

Quoting from the linked `.altmacro` help page:

> single-character string escape
>
> To include any single character
> literally in a string (even if the character would otherwise have some
> special meaning), you can prefix the character with ‘!’ (an
> exclamation mark). For example, you can write ‘<4.3 !> 5.4!!>’ to get
> the literal text ‘4.3 > 5.4!’.

So I tried the following:

```
.macro my_macro b
    // Do something with \b
1:
    !b   1!b
.endm

    my_macro xyz
```

Now I get the following error:

```
Error: junk at end of line, first unrecognized character is `!'
```

Now replacing the `b` instruction by a different one (say `bne`) just for the sake of testing:

```
.macro my_macro b
    // Do something with \b
1:
    bne   1b
.endm

    my_macro xyz
```

This produces the following error, which is in line with the error from the initial version:

```
Error: garbage following instruction -- `bne 1xyz'
```

But something even more interesting happens with the following version:

```
.macro my_macro b
    // Do something with \b
1:
    bne   1!b
.endm

    my_macro xyz
```

The error is now:

```
Error: invalid operands (*ABS* and *UND* sections) for `|~'
```

So, short of changing the parameter name away from `b`, is there anything I can do to get the first `b` in `b 1b` to be recognized as a branch instruction and the second as indicating the branch is to the backwards occurrence of numeric local label `1`, instead of replacing these occurrences of `b` by `xyz`?

Comment: Does `!b !1b` work if you insist on this inconvenient parameter name?  (`param_b` or `vb` (for "variable b") might work well to still have "b" in the name.)

Comment: `bne !1b` gives this error: `Error: garbage following instruction -- 'bne !1xyz'`. I found a workaround using the `LOCAL` directive also introduced by `.altmacro` to create a label name, but I'm still curious why the `!` symbol doesn't do what the manual explicitly says it should do.